# Draw map and parts of map in dialog window

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, viewport, stage

I would like to achieve the following behavior:

Draw a scrollable world map of x*y tiles. Draw a given part of this map inside a dialog window (using the class Dialog). Pretty much the way Transport Tycoon enabled you to see a little part of the world inside a dialog window: https://wiki.openttd.org/images/7/76/Speed-limits.png.
You can be anywhere on the map, but still see the train, plane or any object inside the dialog window.

I am currently clueless about a smart way to achieve this. My current thought can be broken down to using two stages: one for the world and for the UI. I can then draw the Map onto the world stage. But according to this: [Is it possible in LibGDX's `scene2d` API to have the same Actor instance in multiple Stages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649848/is-it-possible-in-libgdxs-scene2d-api-to-have-the-same-actor-instance-in-mult) I cannot simply add the Map or any Actor to another stage because it will be removed from the previous stage.

So I am wondering: What is the most intelligent way to solve this? Is there one? Do I miss something essential here? Thank you for any answer!